# Why does $timeout delay the whole page loading inside $ionicView.Enter?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

As far as i know, $timeout is a promise object in angular, which means the code will go on running without waiting for the timeout to end.

However, when i used it in my ionic code, for some reason it did and the whole loading of the page froze for 6 seconds. Can you please explain why?

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.Enter", function( scopes, states ) {
     $timeout(function(){
        // some function i wrote
     }, 6000);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption around the code continuing to run is wrong - otherwise what would the point of calling `$timeout` be? It's an Angular wrapper and recommended to use in place of window.setTimeout() but works exactly the same. The code above will execute after a 6000ms delay.

[ADDED] From the [Angular API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout): "The return value of calling $timeout is a promise, **which will be resolved when the delay has passed** and the timeout function, if provided, is executed."

Comment: Im sorry, perhaps i do not understand your answer. My problem was that the timeout gets the WHOLE method to get stuck, unlike i expected: to create a promise and let everything go on...

Comment: i can't remember much, but i think u r right and it must have been smth else. i'd like to "close" and issue, Thanks.